# Weird SSH problem

Tags: raspbian, ssh

I've done some googling, and I can't find any answers to my problem: I can't ssh into my Raspberry Pi from my computer (connection timeout), but I can ssh into my web server (dreamhost) and then ssh from there into my Pi. What could be causing this? How do I solve it? I even just reinstalled Raspbian and with a clean install this happens.

Edit (updates):
Running Mac OS X 10.9.4

Ping from my computer:

```
PING ----- (50.30.xxx.xxx): 56 data bytes
ping: sendto: Host is down
ping: sendto: Host is down
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
ping: sendto: Host is down
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
ping: sendto: Host is down
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
ping: sendto: Host is down
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
--- ----- ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
```

Ping from within Dreamhost:

```
PING ----- (50.30.xxx.xxx) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 50.30.xxx.xxx: icmp_req=1 ttl=51 time=21.8 ms
64 bytes from 50.30.xxx.xxx: icmp_req=2 ttl=51 time=21.9 ms

--- ----- ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 28177ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 21.893/21.916/21.940/0.149 ms
```

I'm not using any sort of port forwarding, my apartment complex gives each device a unique public IP.

Route:

```
Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            50.30.232.1        UGSc           26        0     en1
50.30.232/22       link#5             UCS             4        0     en1
50.30.232.1        0:10:f3:30:25:e7   UHLWIir        27        0     en1   1199
50.30.233.135      50:ea:d6:3:cc:13   UHLWI           0        0     en1   1140
50.30.233.xxx      localhost          UHS             0        2     lo0
50.30.234.120      6c:f0:49:ef:a2:fc  UHLWIi          1        0     en1   1098
50.30.235.255      ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI          0       29     en1
127                localhost          UCS             0        0     lo0
localhost          localhost          UH              8   832546     lo0
169.254            link#5             UCS             0        0     en1
```

Comment: Can you ping the Pi from your computer?  Is the computer Windows/Mac/Linux etc?  How are your computer and Pi connected?

Comment: [related](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/7523/7355)?

Comment: You are probably using port forwarding, right?

Comment: I'm not using port forwarding, and see edits for pings

Comment: Will you please post the output of `route`? (Specifically from your home computer).  Does your pi and home computer share a LAN?

Comment: Updated with Route (Netstat -r)

Comment: And yes, I think technically it's a LAN, but the assigned IPs are all public IPs and all ports are open as far as I can tell.

Comment: I should note, this has not happened in the past. Only the last week or so has this been a problem, and I've reinstalled a few times before posting here.

Comment: Please do not conceal information. In this case that is important.

Answer (score 1):

Many network infrastructures that support public machines are configured to not allow 'peer' connections. This way, when a windows machine gets infected, that machine can not contact any other machine on the local network (your neighbors) and crap up their machines too. I believe that your case is by design..

Comment: Unless the complex updated the network recently (unlikely), I haven't had this problem in the past (5-6 weeks ago). Are there any other reasons this could happen?

Answer (score 1):

I had something similar: `ping raspi` worked fine, but `ssh pi@raspi` did not, from my Windows desktop, while it was working fine the day before.
From another Raspberry it acted the same. Reinstalled, searched all over the fora, nothing.

Then I found the problem: I had made a `hosts` file entry because the raspi hostname was not always resolved correctly: `192.168.0.19 raspi`. But then my modem decided to assign this particular ip address to my desktop after a reboot and `ping raspi` was just answered by the desktop, while it refused ssh connections!

**Solved** it by removing the raspi entry from the desktop's hosts file and empty out the .ssh/known_hosts.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/113602)

Answer (score 0):

Are all your interfaces up and running? Are you trying to ssh (wireless) or via LAN cable. If you are doing via the LAN, then your eth0 should be up, and configured as for example:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.1
```

for Mac, view the analogous command, and then try sshing into your raspberry pi.

Also, you could view the raspberry pi's interfaces settings and see if something is out of place. You could post the interfaces file here for us to figure out, perhaps?

In RPi, the n/w interfaces file is located in

```
nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Comment: I think you missed the point where everything works, I can ssh just fine from my mac into my web server, and can ssh from my web server to the pi, but not from my mac to the pi

Comment: try sudo ssh when trying to ssh from mac into pi, it used to work for me when it would take a lot of time(too long). (It could be a bad suggestion)

Comment: it could be something about the n/w architecture, you cannot ping from local n/w (lan) to a public ip n/w(upper).